# "client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')" "commands" says "not definied"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm coding a Discord bot, and this message appeared. I also included all libraries, but it's not working. I don't know what to do. Need help. Any suggestions?

```py
client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')
client.remove_command('help')
```

Here's the message:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you haven't imported a necessary library. Try adding:

```
from discord.ext import commands
```

Above those three lines